# zfr-rest and apigilty difference

Tags: rest, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

What is the difference between zfr-rest and apigilty. Which one should be used in which circumstances? AS far as I can see zfr-rest is simple and can be used to deliver any payload where as apigilty seems like bound to return only HAL. Which one should be best to use/learn. apigility probably will be included in zf3. Any information of experience, ideas with these two will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[ZF-Rest](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-rest)** is a ZF2 module that according to the docs:

> provides structure and code for quickly implementing RESTful APIs that use JSON as a transport.

**[Apigility](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility)** is a ZF2 application or as they write in the docs a Meta-Module:

> Meta- Zend Framework 2 module combining features from:
>
> - zf-api-problem
> - zf-content-negotiation
> - zf-hal
> - zf-rest
> - zf-rpc
> - zf-versioning

Apigility requires ZF-Rest as you can see [here on line 44 inside the `composer.json` file](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility/blob/master/composer.json#L44) for the application, so it is an application dependency.

Thus, you cannot use Apigility without ZF-Rest, but you can use ZF-Rest without Apigility.

You also mention HAL inside your question. There is a separate module called **[ZF-Hal](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-hal)** providing the HAL-Json functionality in Apigility. This module seamlessly connects to ZF-Rest.

I hope this will make it more understandable it all relates.

Comment: Is there any way to use  any other payload other than HAL in apigility?

Comment: @varuog Yes, you can connect your own RenderStrategy and render whatever you want :)